# JavaScript function to be executed in the last after all other scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal which automatically opens up after certain time period. The code to open the modal is written in a js file.

```
- xyz.js

 var timehandle

 //setTimeout function

        timehandle=window.setTimeout("func()",x);

  //function to open the modal

      func(){

       $('#modal').show();
     }
```

i am clearing the timer from a jsp in order to avoid modal being opened.

```
 - abc.jsp

   <script>

      head.ready(function() {

         $(document).ready(function () {

                window.clearTimeout(timehandle);

         });

      });
   </script>
```

however, document.ready in the jsp is called earlier than the function to load the modal based on setTimeout. Can anyone tell me how do I make sure that the clearTimeout is called after the js file has been executed?

Comment: try `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<body onload="myFunction()">` since what you really want it to execute your js code after the page has loaded.

> Execute a JavaScript immediately after a page has been loaded

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)